# Flutter Deeplink issue with image URL

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, flutter-deep-link

I am facing an issue with deeplink part. When I try to `jsonEncode`, I got this error as shown in the attachment:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The JSON is not valid, hence the `FormatException`.

The `logo` key is not well formatted as it doesn't have an enclosing double quote `"`.

This is what you have right now.

```
"logo": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/ve/b/..appspot.com/o/Stores/image_picker_78CC1DE1-00A6-4479-924F-8D0662B740B-48237-000060FE8F8282CB.jpg?alt=media,
```

This is what the key supposed to look like in the Map.

```
"logo": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/ve/b/..appspot.com/o/Stores/image_picker_78CC1DE1-00A6-4479-924F-8D0662B740B-48237-000060FE8F8282CB.jpg?alt=media",
```

Comment: I have traced the jsonEncode data object, and I found that logo is set correctly with enclosing double quote ". The issue happened when I try to read/fetch the deep link.